# Shell script starting passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, shell, scripting, cron

I have a shell script that starts a passenger instance if it is not running:

```
#!/bin/bash
/usr/sbin/lsof -i :82 > /home/var/www/site-owner/data/www/site.com/currenttest
if [ ! -s /home/var/www/site-owner/data/www/site.com/currenttest ];
  then
    cd /home/var/www/site-owner/data/www/site.com/current/
    passenger start -p 82 -d -e production --user site-owner
fi
```

It works very good if I start it from root ssh environment. 
I tried to start it from crontab and it didn't start with error: "passenger_loader.sh: line 12: passenger: command not found".

By many hours of googling I found crontab from root user and root console user have different environments but, anyway, I don't understand how to make a crontab root user run scripts like root console user. I started to add

```
source ~/.bash_profile
source ~/.bashrc
```

to a script but it didn't change anything.

Comment: Try to use the absolute path to `passenger`

Comment: Nameless, I tried this - error changes to "/usr/bin/env: ruby_noexec_wrapper: No such file or directory"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont't know if it is a solution, but it works like I need (I started it from bash):

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then
    . ~/.bashrc
fi

HOME=/root
PATH=/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p374@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p374/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/root/bin:/root/bin
export HOME PATH

/usr/sbin/lsof -i :82 > /home/var/www/site-owner/data/www/site.com/currenttest
if [ ! -s /home/var/www/site-owner/data/www/site.com/currenttest ];
  then
    # passenger down
    date
    #. "/usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm"
    rvm use 1.9.3
    cd /home/var/www/site-owner/data/www/site.com/current/
    passenger start -p 82 -d -e production --user site-owner
fi
```